# Swift/Firebase copy path

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically I am struggling with copying paths to other destinations. I have a directory with root/users/id/info, like this:

```
users{
  id{
    username:Andreas
    dob:12/12/2012
    hobby:football
  }
}
```

However, what I want to accomplish, is to move the path with the ID (that contains all the information about andreas, to another path `(root/HighestRanking/)` so it looks like this: `(root/HighestRanking/andreasUID/info)`, but I can't seem to find a way to do so. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance..

Here is the code I currently have:

```
ref.child("Users").child(uid).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded) { (snap:FIRDataSnapshot) in 
  var pathway = snap
  self.ref.child("HighestRanking").child(uid)..setValue([pathway], withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in                              
     if error != nil {
         print("An error occured.")
     } else {
         print("Success.")
     }   
  }
```

//An error occurs.. Tried several other methods as well..

Comment: What event should trigger the "copy"? Do you already have the user id and data? Any code to show us?

Comment: @adolfosrs I provided some more code now. And the trigger will simply be a button (@UIButton).

Comment: Why copy or move all of that data? Could you just create a reference to it?

Comment: @Jay Simply because I wanted to display the data two places. And that's also what I tried, but my problem got solved.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the data changes - for example the user changes his hobby to 'stamp collecting' from 'football' you'll have to change data in multiple locations. That's exacerbated if you have it in multiple locations. Whereas if you store a reference to the data itself - the user id in this case, if the hobby changes you only have to change it one time in one location.

Comment: How would I approach it if I wanted to create a reference to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking for is something like the following:

```
ref.child("Users").child(uid).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
  if let data = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject] {
    self.ref.child("HighestRanking").child(uid).setValue(data)
  }
})
```

Observe that since you want to "copy" the data when a `UIButton` is triggered you should be using `FIRDataEventType.Value` instead of `FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! Saved me lots of time.